# React js - make button link to a different app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to make a button to link to a different app with react librery.
my code looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import "./subportfolio.scss";

import Coffee1 from "../../assets/coffee-1.jpg";
import Coffee2 from "../../assets/coffee-2.jpg";
import Coffee3 from "../../assets/coffee-3.jpg";
import Coffee4 from "../../assets/coffee-4.jpg";
import CoffeeShop from "../../assets/coffee-shop-1.jpg";
import Tea1 from "../../assets/tea-1.jpg";
import Tea2 from "../../assets/tea-2.jpg";
import Tea3 from "../../assets/tea-3.jpg";

class SubPortfolio extends Component {
  state = {
    projectImg: {
      project1: Coffee1,
      project2: Coffee2,
      project3: Coffee3,
      project4: Coffee4,
      project5: CoffeeShop,
      project6: Tea1,
      project7: Tea2,
      project8: Tea3
    },
    direct: ""
  };

  directToGithub = () => {
    this.props.history.go("https://github.com");
  };
  render() {

    console.log(this.state.direct);
    return (
      <div className="subPortfolio">
        <div className="subPortfolio__content">

          <div className="subPortfolio__content--detail">
            <h2>Image Format</h2>
            <div className="subPortfolio__content--refer">

              <div className="subPortfolio__content--button">
                <button
                  id="github"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={this.directToGithub}
                >
                  github
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SubPortfolio;
```

I tried all of the history properties but all of them throw an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined
SubPortfolio.directToGithub
C:/Users/Ermais Kidane/Documents/REACT/portfolio/src/components/subportfolio/subportfolio.js:30
  27 |  };
  28 | 
  29 |  directToGithub = () => {
> 30 |    this.props.history.go("https://github.com");
     | ^  31 |  };
  32 |  render() {
  33 |    // const projectsImage = Object.keys(this.state.projectImg).map(proImg => {
```

I tried using Link React-router-dom and to adds to with the previous url like (http://localhost:3000/https://github.com) and does not take make anywhere.

how could I make the link to another web site? thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you use `<BrowserRouter>`? Can you please show `App.js` how you are setting up the router part? Thanks!

Comment: You only really use the <Link> to get directed internally with you application, are you trying to make a link to an external site or an internal component?

Comment: Why not use the good old `<a>` tag?

Comment: when I use the `a` tag in react app it throws a warning?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get directed to an external website, just use the standard `<a></a>` tag

```
<a href="https://www.github.com"><button id="github" type="button">github</button></a>
```

if you are trying to use the `<Link>` to get directed to an internal link, it would look more like this

```
<Link to="/github"><button id="github" type="button">github</button></Link>
```

And the link would then have to be setup in the app.js using the router to then be directed to the named component

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically direct to an external website, you can also use `window.location = "https://github.com"` or, assuming a global `window` object, `location = "https://github.com"`.